# Notation on vector calculus

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation, jacobian

Just trying to figure out the proper representations of some vector/matrix systems. So Let's say I have a nonlinear system of ODEs

\begin{align}   
\frac{dx_i}{dt} = f_i(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n,t) \quad i = 1,\dots,n \tag{A}
\end{align}

May I write (and is this conventional) to write system as

$$F(x) \tag{B}$$

where $x$ is the $n$-dimensional solution vector with $i$-th entry $x_i$. And where $F$ represents the vector of functions $f_i$ applied to the system above?

Furthermore if I wanted to take the Jacobian of $F(x)$ would I write

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \tag{C}$$

because I'm not sure if I'm correct about how it's applied in terms of vector operations. I believe it could be written

$$\left[\partial /\partial x_1, \dots, \partial /\partial x_1\right]^T   
\left[f_1(x), \dots, f_2(x)\right]$$

Comment: Yes, that is quite convenient. But I recommend that you explain your notations, e.g. $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n),$ $F = (F_1, \ldots, F_n) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ and $\partial F / \partial x = (\partial F_i / \partial x_j).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is reasonable,

$$
\frac{{\rm d}{\bf x}}{{\rm d}t} = {\bf F}({\bf x}, t)
$$

represents the dynamical system, and

$$
{\bf J} = \frac{\partial {\bf F}}{\partial {\bf x}}
$$

its Jacobian, which can be also written as

$$
{\bf J} = \begin{pmatrix}
\partial f_1/\partial x_1 & \cdots & \partial f_1/\partial x_n \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\partial f_n/\partial x_1 & \cdots & \partial f_m/\partial x_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The last expression clearly depends on they way you arrange the components of your vectors (column vs. row)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one writes $\dot{x}=\mathbb f(x)$ with $x(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for the explicit system, and $0=F( x,\dot{x})$ for the implicit system. The Jacobian of a function $f$ can be written as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. The most common definition for the Jacobian is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots& &\ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_2} & \dots & \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\neq
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\\
\vdots\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(x)&
f_2(x)&
\dots&
f_n(x)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
But I believe some people define it as the transposed of what I've written (which may work, too, and would match your equation).